# Api-platform 2.7+ "subresource" YAML confirm

Tags: api-platform.com

In api-platform 2.7+ I'm trying to create a 'subresource' (I know subresources don't technically exist in 2.7). I can define the subresource link using Attributes, but I need to be able to **define this in YAML** but I cannot find any documentation that shows the format.

For example, this works, but I need to do it in YAML:

```php
#[ApiResource]
class Document
{
```

```php
#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/documents/{id}/previews',
    operations: [ new GetCollection() ],
    uriVariables: [
        'id' => new Link(toProperty: 'document', fromClass: Document::class)
    ]
)]
class Preview
```

Answer (score 1):

That's quite simple:

```yaml
resources:
    Path\To\Your\Document:
        operations:
            ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection:
                uriTemplate: 'documents/{id}/previews'
                uriVariables:
                    id:
                        fromClass: Path\To\Your\Document
                        toProperty: document
```